# Operator '-' is not defined for type 'Double' and type 'DBNull'. [vb.net datagridview]

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

Here I am getting the following bracketed error (Operator '-' is not defined for type 'Double' and type 'DBNull'.) when executing the NetValueValidation().  But its working in the column of "discper" after executing DiscPerValidation()

```
Private Sub grdPurchase_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdPurchase.CellEndEdit
    CellEdited = True
    CurrentColumn = e.ColumnIndex
    CurrentRow = e.RowIndex
    If Me.grdPurchase.Columns(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name = "itemcode" Then
        If Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("itemcode").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
            SeekItemDetails()
        End If
    Else
        If Me.grdPurchase.Columns(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name = "packingratio" Then
            PackingRatioValidation()
        ElseIf Me.grdPurchase.Columns(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name = "price" Then
            PriceValidation()
            NetValueValidation()
        ElseIf Me.grdPurchase.Columns(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name = "grossamt" Then
            GrossAmtValidation()
            'NetValueValidation()
        ElseIf Me.grdPurchase.Columns(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name = "kgs" Then
            KGSValid()
            'NetValueValidation()
        ElseIf Me.grdPurchase.Columns(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name = "discper" Then
            DiscPerValidation()
            'NetValueValidation()
        End If
        SendKeys.Send("{UP}" + "{TAB}")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PackingRatioValidation()
    If Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("packingratio").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("packingratio_temp").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("itemcode").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("qty").Value = _
            Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("packingratio").Value * _
            Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("packingratio_temp").Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PriceValidation()
    If Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("itemcode").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("qty").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("price").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value = Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("price").Value * _
            Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("qty").Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GrossAmtValidation()
    If Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("itemcode").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("qty").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("price").Value = Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value / _
            Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("qty").Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub KGSValid()
    If Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("itemcode").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("qty").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("price").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("kgrate").Value = Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value / _
            Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("kgs").Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DiscPerValidation()
    If Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("itemcode").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
            Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("discper").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("discamt").Value = _
            (Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value / 100) * _
            Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("discper").Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NetValueValidation()
    If Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("itemcode").Value Is DBNull.Value And _
    Not Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("netvalue").Value = _
        Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value - _
        Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("discamt").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated, but the amount of copy/pasted bits is making my eye twitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message means that in this code:

```
Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("grossamt").Value - _    
Me.grdPurchase.Rows(Me.grdPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells("discamt").Value
```

One of the 2 cells is `DBNull`.  Based on the message, it is a cell involved in subtraction, which is these 2.  The odd thing is that else where you are testing cell after cell for `DBNull`, but not here.

---

Not for nothing, but you have lots and lots of unneeded code there which makes it hard to see this type of thing.  For instance the big If Block in CellEndEdit could be simplified something like:

```
Dim name As String = dgv2.Rows(e.ColumnIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString
Select Case name
    Case "price"
        PriceValidation(e.RowIndex)
        NetValueValidation(...)
    Case "grossamt"
        GrossAmtValidation(...)
End Select
```

I'm not sure why you arent using the event args available.  Then something like this is all you need for `PriceValidation` (passing the row to work on to it from the `EventArgs`):

```
Private Sub PriceValidation(r As Int32) 
    ' note: this is DOING pricing, not validation
    Dim quan = SafeConvert(dgv.Rows(r).Cells("qty").Value)
    Dim price = SafeConvert(dgv.Rows(r).Cells("price").Value)

    dgv.Rows(r).Cells("grossamt").Value = (quan * price)
End Sub
```

I suspect `Option Strict` is not on -- but it should be:

```
grdPurchase.Rows(...).Cells("qty").Value = _
grdPurchase.Rows(...).Cells("packingratio").Value * _
grdPurchase.Rows(...).Cells("packingratio_temp").Value
```

A cell value returns object, not a number, so that code is trying to multiply 2 Objects.  A simple procedure you could use to both test for DBNull on *value* cells (used above in PriceValidation):

```
' helper function to convert a DBNull
Private Function SafeConvert(v As Object) As Double
    If System.DBNull.Value.Equals(v) Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Dim d As Double = 0
        If Double.TryParse(v.ToString, d) Then

        End If
        Return d
    End If
End Function
```

It would work on cells that have Quantity or Price but not Item Code (text).  Whenever you find yourself typing the same code over and over (and over), stop and look for a better way.

Comment: Plutonix,,... thanks a lot.... I have done my job through ur code.. I expect  ur help in future also... (Y) :)